# как использовать Selenium в android

Tags: android, selenium

Добрый день.

цель приложения:

```
   1.получить логин пароль от пользователя;
   2.открыть браузер в фоновом режиме;
   3.пройти по url и заполнить форму и нажать на кнопку"войти";
   4.получить таблицу и вывести полученные данные.
```

Все это должно работать в фоновом режиме. 
Можно ли это реализовать с помощью selenium?
если да можете скинуть ссылку на примеры? ооочень нужно)))))